# Display 2D text on screen simply

Tags: java, lwjgl, slick2d

I have been looking through forum posts, blogs, videos, and various other websites for the past hour trying to figure out how to display text on the screen. From what I have seen this is not very simple to do. (Maybe it is once you know how to actually do it)

I decided (with a bit of regret) to post this question here. I am sorry if this question has already been asked a million times, but I am just not understanding how to get this to work. All of the code I have tried so far has not worked.

I would just like to know how I can display text on the screen. I do not want to use my own font or anything fancy. I would just like to know the simplest way to display text on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to use Slick. Here's a link to the page specifically about loading and using fonts within your LWJGL program:
[Slick-Util (Part 3) - TrueType Fonts for LWJGL](http://ninjacave.com/slickutil3)

Answer (score -1):

I am learning java currently and I love the newbostin, he makes simple fast tutorials but to display text I'm pretty sure u need to 
1: have eclipse
2: make the base of it (the main string, idk how actually)
3. The actual code to do it is println("text here")
I'm not completely sure so you should check out the newBoston he is awesome at explaining.

Comment: I should have made this a lot more clear in my question, I am talking about display text on a window using LWJGL, not in the console.

Comment: Please read the question before answering. OP wasn't talking about printing to the console.